# ruby on rails: need a function to calculate the time and display it in multi language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, time

I need a custom function to calculate the times given from a certain point in the future X

It should countdown from 1 hour to zero

- 1 hour
- 59 min
- 59 min
- ..
- 10 min
- 9 min
- ..
- 1 min
- 59 sec
- 58 sec
- 57 sec
- ..
- 1 sec

Im currently using the

`= clean_text distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, real_time, true)`

With the clean_text function:

```
def clean_text(string)
bad_words = ["less than", "about"]
change_words = ["hours", "minutes"]

bad_words.each do |bad|
  string.gsub!(bad + " ", '')
end

string = string.gsub("hours", "hrs")
string = string.gsub("minutes", "min")
string = string.gsub("minute", "min")
string = string.gsub("half a min", "30 sec")
string = string.gsub("seconds", "sec")

return string
```

end

But this is insufficient since Im rewriting "minutes" to "min" etc. What would be a good start to write such a custom function for time? I guess it will be quite complex but wondered if there are any rails internal functions I could use?

I need

- countdown like listed above
- it has to be i18n compatible so I can do 1 hour / 1 houra, etc

Anyone an idea or will it be a custom function  thats really neccesairly here?